# intersection of Altitudes of a triangle

Tags: geometry

consider a triangle ABC, and let AD and BE be two altitudes of the triangle, with D and E as their respective intersections with the opposite sides BC and AC and let them intersect at o. prove that a line from vertex c passing through o is also an altitude
please help
you may try using circles

Comment: Please add a drawing of this to your question.

Comment: Is the triangle required to be acute?

Answer (score 1):

[image: altitude and perpendicular lines]

I add the picture, to see that for example DC=CE consider the parallelograms ABCD and ABCE, same thing with the other sides

Answer (score 0):

Draw parallels to all three sides through the oposite edges, than the altitudes  become  the perpendicular bisectors, and it is known or easy to prove that all three meet at one point.

Comment: no the altitude doesnt become perpendicular bisector because they are not chords of a circle